# Particular solution of $y'' + y = -2x c e^{-2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving $$y'' + y = -2x \cdot c \cdot e^{-2x}$$

The homogenous ODE is $y'' + y = 0 \implies y^{(H)} = Ae^{ix} + \overline{A}e^{-ix}, A \in \mathbb{C}$

but for the particular solution I have not been able to solve. I have tried plugging in variations of $xe^{-2x}$, but it doesn't seem to work out. Can anyone please guide me on how to obtain the particular solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

The best way is to begin by eliminating the exponential term after putting
$$y=ze^{-2x}$$
with
$$y'=(z'-2z)e^{-2x}\;$$
$$\;y''=(z''-4z'+4z)e^{-2x}$$

the new equation is
$$z''-4z'+5z=-2xc$$
from here, a particular solution $ z_p $ could be a polynom of degree $ 1$ of the form
$$z_p=ax+b$$
with
$$-4a+5(ax+b)=-2cx$$
so
$$a=\frac{-2c}{5}\text{ and } b=\frac{-8c}{25}$$

the particular solution will be
$$y_p=z_pe^{-2x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. When we have exponential on RHS is trying to get rid of it always a good approach?